# UUID validation in HTTP headers doesn't work?

Tags: java, rest, validation, http, uuid

I have been getting this really weird bug and I'm not sure how to go about it.

I currently have a service that uses `RESTful` endpoints, and has a header which is supposed to be a `UUID`. It works just fine with regular UUIDs and clearly non-UUID values such as `2bcd-d2efc`, but when encountering a UUID such as `4c95b7e9-5051-4e5b-be30-eed67988`, in which it is missing 4 hex values at the end, upon receiving it at my REST Controller, the value it takes becomes something like `4c95b7e9-5051-4e5b-be30-0000eed67988`.

This makes the initially invalid UUID bypass the UUID typecast validation we have in place.

Any ideas on why this zero padding occurs (which I assume has to do with serialization) and how to fix it? The controller is implemented in Java 8 if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at `UUID.fromString` you can see that it doesn't enforce a minimum length. `UUID.fromString("0-0-0-0-0").toString()` will return "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000". So, as far as `UUID` is concerned, what you passed in is equivalent to what it looks like when it arrives.

Comment: Is there a way to enforce the length? I am also doing a direct typecast using `(UUID)`, does this make a difference?